# Updating training documents for gensim Doc2Vec model

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

I have an existing gensim Doc2Vec model, and I'm trying to do iterative updates to the training set, and by extension, the model.

I take the new documents, and perform preproecssing as normal:

```
stoplist = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
train_corpus= []
for i, document in enumerate(corpus_update['body'].values.tolist()):
     train_corpus.append(gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument([word for word in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(document) if word not in stoplist], [i]))
```

I then load the original model, update the vocabulary, and retrain:

```
#### Original model
## model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(dm=0, size=300, hs=1, min_count=10, dbow_words= 1, negative=5, workers=cores)

model = Doc2Vec.load('pvdbow_model_6_06_12_17.doc2vec')

model.build_vocab(train_corpus, update=True)

model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
```

I then update the training set Pandas dataframe by appending the new data, and reset the index.

```
corpus = corpus.append(corpus_update)
corpus = corpus.reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, when I try to use infer_vector() with the *updated* model:

```
inferred_vector = model1.infer_vector(tokens)
sims = model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=len(model.docvecs))
```

the result quality is poor, suggesting that the indices from the model and the training set dataframe no longer match.

When I compare it against the *non-updated* training set dataframe (again using the updated model) the results are fine - though, obviously I'm missing the new documents.

Is there anyway to have both updated, as I want to be able to make frequent updates to the model without a full retrain of the model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gensim `Doc2Vec` doesn't yet have official support for expanding-the-vocabulary (via `build_vocab(..., update=True)`), so the model's behavior here is not defined to do anything useful. In fact, I think any existing doc-tags will be completely discarded and replaced with any in the latest corpus. (Additionally, there are outstanding unresolved reports of memory-fault process-crashes when trying to use `update_vocab()` with `Doc2Vec`, such as [this issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1019).)

Even if that worked, there are a number of murky balancing issues to consider if ever continuing to call `train()` on a model with texts different than the initial training-set. In particular, each such training session will nudge the model to be better on the new examples, but lose value of the original training, possibly making the model worse for some cases or overall.

The most defensible policy with a growing corpus would be to occasionally retrain from scratch with all training examples combined into one corpus. Another outline of a possible process for rolling updates to a model was discussed in [my recent post to the gensim discussion list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/7pLHl0D9br4/xIaoNvaXAwAJ).

A few other comments on your setup:

- using both hierarchical-softmax (`hs=1`) and negative sampling (with `negative` > 0) increases the model size and training time, but may not offer any advantage compared to using just one mode with more iterations (or other tweaks) – so it's rare to have both modes active
- by not specifying an `iter`, you're using the default-inherited-from-Word2Vec of '5', while published Doc2Vec work often uses 10-20 or more iterations
- many report `infer_vector` working better with a much-higher value for its optional parameter `steps` (which has a default of only `5`), and/or with smaller values of `alpha` (which has a default of `0.1`)

Comment: Hi @gojomo, do you know if this is still the case? Or does Gensim `Doc2Vec` now support updating a model with new text?

Comment: You can always infer doc-vectors from new texts, with regard to already known words. Also, you can always send the model new training docs, while it ignores new words/tags, but there are still the relative-balance/compatibility issues I mentioned. But through `gensim-3.8.3 (current version as of September 2020), if you want to try to expand the `Doc2Vec` model's vocabulary, the `.build_vocab(..., update=True)` option still isn't tested, reported to crash, and *also* subject to the same balance/compatibility issues as above.

Comment: Aha, that all makes sense, @gojomo. Thanks very much for the in-depth answer - it makes things crystal clear and is much appreciated!