# How to use doc2vec model in production?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I wonder how to deploy a doc2vec model in production to create word vectors as input features to a classifier. To be specific, let say, a doc2vec model is trained on a corpus as follows.

```
dataset['tagged_descriptions'] = datasetf.apply(lambda x: doc2vec.TaggedDocument(
            words=x['text_columns'], tags=[str(x.ID)]), axis=1)

model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, min_count=1, epochs=150, workers=cores,
                                window=5, hs=0, negative=5, sample=1e-5, dm_concat=1)

corpus = dataset['tagged_descriptions'].tolist()

model.build_vocab(corpus)

model.train(corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

and then it is dumped into a pickle file. The word vectors are used to train a classifier such as random forests to predict movies sentiment.

Now suppose that in production, there is a document entailing some totally new vocabularies. That being said, they were not among the ones present during the training of the doc2vec model. I wonder how to tackle such a case.

As a side note, I am aware of [Updating training documents for gensim Doc2Vec model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775557/updating-training-documents-for-gensim-doc2vec-model) and [Gensim: how to retrain doc2vec model using previous word2vec model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252207/gensim-how-to-retrain-doc2vec-model-using-previous-word2vec-model). However, I would appreciate more lights to be shed on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Doc2Vec` model will only be able to report trained-up vectors for documents that were present during training, and only be able to `infer_vector()` new doc-vectors for texts containing words that were present during training. (Unrecognized words passed to `.infer_vector()` will be ignored, similar to the way any words appearing fewer than `min_count` times are ignored during training.)

If over time you acquire many new texts with new vocabulary words, and those words are important, you'll have to occasionally re-train the `Doc2Vec` model. And, after re-training, the doc-vectors from the re-trained model will generally not be comparable to doc-vectors from the original model – so downstream classifiers and other applications using the doc-vectors will need updating, as well.

Your own production/deployment requirements will drive how often this re-training should happen, and old models replaced with newer ones.

(While a `Doc2Vec` model can be fed new training data at any time, doing so incrementally as a sort of 'fine-tuning' introduces hairy issues of balance between old and new data. And, there's no official gensim support for expanding existing the vocabulary of a `Doc2Vec` model. So, the most robust course is to retrain from scratch using all available data.)

A few side notes on your example training code:

- it's rare for `min_count=1` to be a good idea: rare words often serve as 'noise', without sufficient usage examples to model well, and thus 'noise' that just slows/interferes with patterns that can be learned from more common-words
- `dm_concat=1` is best considered an experimental/advanced mode, as it makes models significantly larger and slower to train, with unproven benefits.
- much published work uses just 10-20 training epochs; smaller datasets or smaller docs will sometimes benefit from more, but 150 may be taking a lot of time with very little marginal benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer and side notes.